# Paeth Filter/Algorithm not working correctly for PNG

Tags: c++, image, png

I'm trying to binary read png's.

Reading images that only use the None, sub, up or average filter work fine.
I used the documentation as described here: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Filters.html

Original picure:
[image: Original picture]

*** Pixel struct ***

```
 struct Pixel
    {
        unsigned char r,g,b;
        int all() const { return r + g + b; }
        Pixel& operator+=(const Pixel& rhs)
        {
            this->r = (this->r + rhs.r) % 256;
            this->g = (this->g + rhs.g) % 256;
            this->b = (this->b + rhs.b) % 256;
            return *this;
        }
        Pixel& operator-=(const Pixel& rhs)
        {
            this->r = (this->r - rhs.r) % 256;
            this->g = (this->g - rhs.g) % 256;
            this->b = (this->b - rhs.b) % 256;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator<=(const Pixel& rhs)
        {
            return ((this->r <= rhs.r) && (this->g <= rhs.g) && (this->b <= rhs.b));
        }   
        friend Pixel& operator+(Pixel lhs, const Pixel& rhs)
        {
            lhs += rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
        friend Pixel& operator-(Pixel lhs, const Pixel& rhs)
        {
            lhs -= rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
    };
```

*** First possibility ***

```
 void INC_Image::Paeth(std::vector<Pixel>& thesePixels, std::vector<Pixel>& priorPixels) const
    {
        for (int i{ 1 }; i < thesePixels.size(); i++)
        {
            Pixel tempPixel = thesePixels[i];
            tempPixel.r = (thesePixels[i].r + PaethPredictor(thesePixels[i - 1].r, priorPixels[i].r, priorPixels[i - 1].r)) % 256;
            tempPixel.g = (thesePixels[i].g + PaethPredictor(thesePixels[i - 1].g, priorPixels[i].g, priorPixels[i - 1].g)) % 256;
            tempPixel.b = (thesePixels[i].b + PaethPredictor(thesePixels[i - 1].b, priorPixels[i].b, priorPixels[i - 1].b)) % 256;
            thesePixels[i] = tempPixel;

        }
    }
    unsigned char INC_Image::PaethPredictor(const unsigned char& previous, const unsigned char& prior, const unsigned char& priorPrevious) const
    {
        auto p = (previous + prior - priorPrevious) ;
        auto pa = abs(p - previous) ;
        auto pb = abs(p - prior) ;
        auto pc = abs(p - priorPrevious) ;

        if (pa <= pb && pa <= pc) return previous ;
        else if (pb <= pc) return prior;
        else return (priorPrevious );
    }
```

With thesePixels == vector of 1 image line.

With priorPixels == vector of previous image line.

Result:[image: Result]

*** Second possibility ***

```
void INC_Image::Paeth(std::vector<Pixel>& thesePixels, std::vector<Pixel>& priorPixels) const
    {
        for (int i{ 1 }; i < thesePixels.size(); i++)
        {
            thesePixels[i] += PaethPredictor(thesePixels[i - 1], priorPixels[i], priorPixels[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    Pixel INC_Image::PaethPredictor(const Pixel& previous, const Pixel& prior, const Pixel& priorPrevious) const
    {
        auto p = previous.all() + prior.all() - priorPrevious.all();
        auto pa = abs(p - previous.all());
        auto pb = abs(p - prior.all());
        auto pc = abs(p - priorPrevious.all());

        if (pa <= pb && pa <= pc) return previous;
        else if (pb <= pc) return prior;
        else return priorPrevious;

    }
```

With thesePixels == vector of 1 image line.

With priorPixels == vector of previous image line.

Result: [image: Result]

I don't know what's wrong with the calculation.

Comment: Why don't you just use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)?

Comment: Trying to do it myself, as a personal project, without using any libraries (ofc the zlib library for inflating is something I have to use). 
It's nothing more than a trying to expand my programming/c++ knowledge, and I like binary reading ;)

Comment: `Pixel::operator+` (and `operator-`) are flawed because the return a reference to a local that is going away.  The `operator<=` is highly suspicious because there is a large range of values where neither value is <= the other.  And in `INC_Image::PaethPredictor`, you calculate `p` by subtracting `priorPrevious.all()` but when calculating `pc` you subtract it again, unlike `pa` and `pb` where you subtract values that you added.